# Feeding two DACs with same input

Tags: dac

Can I feed same digital signal to two DACs and take the average of the outputs of two DACs. What precautions should be taken?

Comment: Yes; yes; make sure your averager circuit doesn't excessively load the DAC outputs. But what would you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: To improve noise performance

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't bother. The problem is that if you don't know how to do this, you're likely unaware of a lot of more serious sources of noise than someone who designs DACs for a living, things like different noise profiles in resistors, opamp voltage/current noise, etc. Unless you want to average *different* signals, which is one way to get more bits out of several DACs.

Comment: You're more likely to be introducing more noise with all the extras than you could even best-case-theoretically reduce with this technique.

Comment: Such an approach will reduce noise only if you can show that the noise introduced *by each DAC* is statistically independent. It will have no effect at all on any other noise sources in the system, including any "dithering" that may exist in the digital data stream.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do that, and I heard this is a common practice among audio fanatics.

How you average depends on the outputs: you shouldn't just connect two 'stiff' (low-impedance) outputs together, but you could connect two current outputs.

Google 'analog summation'.

Comment: ... it's spelled "audiophools" :-)

Comment: I was trying to avoid that mindset, but I did have visions of guys wielding platinum-coated power cords.

Comment: @DaveTweed Perhaps "audio enthusiasts" works better?

Comment: @landroni: No, the slightly derogatory connotation is deliberate. There are plenty of audiophiles who apply solid scientific and engineering principles to their hobby. But there are others who buy into the hype, pseudoscience and faulty logic that abounds in the business, and they're just being "phoolish" with their time and money. It is our job to use gentle persuasion on the latter who show up here to turn them into the former. But it's an uphill battle, because sometimes it can be difficult to figure out what the underlying misconceptions are and address them.

Comment: @DaveTweed While appreciate this point of view, it is a matter of significant debate who is being "phoolish" in this scenario, and who is falling prey to wielding pseudo-science or deeply-held misconceptions. See these two recent discussions on the matter: [The Audio Subjectivist vs the Objectivist ‘duality’](http://www.head-fi.org/t/781268/the-diyrs-cookbook/315#post_12407403) and [Sound Science vs Sound Engineering](http://www.head-fi.org/t/784471/what-a-long-strange-trip-its-been-robert-hunter/480#post_12407199). Using such terms only invites antagonism and not constructive discussion...

Comment: @landroni: ... and then there are those who think they are philosophers as well as "audio enthusiasts". Look, you're now making my point for me. I really don't have time for this kind of mumbo-jumbo. I'm busy making a living at this sort of thing, where *measurable* and *repeatable* results are the only thing that counts in the end.

Comment: @DaveTweed This isn't the right venue for such a discussion, so I'll only say this: The 2nd post is by Mike Moffat, who is hardly an audio enthusiast or a philosopher if you're familiar with his work; his DACs are often glued to a testing bench. The 1st post is by a type who won't listen to gear without first thoroughly measuring its specs in his own system. But your antagonism is telling... Those who argue about measurability and repeatability indulge in the exact same philosophical arguing as the two posts quoted. So here's a rhetorical question: how can science measure transmitted emotions?

Answer (score 0):

Just take some high-end DACs with current output. They can be used in parallel without any special circuitry.

Since you have a current output you need a current to voltage converter.